# installing symfony on XAMPP for Linux 5.6.20

Tags: linux, xampp

I installed xampp for linux 5.6.2 , (opensuse leap distribution), xampp its working fine, but when i tried to install symfony nothing happends, no error no messaje no install. im doing exactly like page says. but nothing happens.
My steps are:

```
sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

( no message from terminal , see the screeshot )

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

( no message error on screen , see the screenshot )

```
symfony new my_project
```

( no message from screen )

And nothing more happens.
What its missing? what iam doing wrong.
thanks in advance!
Max

Screenshoot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRnFp.jpg

Comment: Maybe the output from ``strace symfony new my_project`` can give you some clues?

Answer (score 0):

Have you php-phar installed? It's needed...

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. I know you don't have enough rep yet (you need 50), but please do not post answers as this one to circumvent the system. Instead, wait until you have enough reputation. Thank you!

Comment: Oh sorry, answer should be "could you check php-phar is available and install if not, http://php.net/manual/en/phar.installation.php "